# xcode 8 beta 3: Expected ',' joining parts of a multi-clause condition

Tags: swift, conditional-statements, swift3

Getting a new warning in xcode 8 beta 3.  What is wrong with this syntax, or is there a bug in xcode?

SwiftyJSON.swift:772:35: Expected ',' joining parts of a multi-clause condition

```
if let errorValue = error where errorValue.code == ErrorNotExist {
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It seems this feature has been included:
[0099-conditionclauses.md](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0099-conditionclauses.md)

Try this:

```
if let errorValue = error, errorValue.code == ErrorNotExist {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link - it was very hard for me to find how the syntax had changed until I saw that.

Comment: This is the crucial part: **"where clauses are no longer used to conjoin Boolean expressions with conditional binding. This fixes user confusion issues and addresses a problem where Boolean conditions need to be attached to arbitrary bindings."** So, use comma instead.

Comment: what if my code is base on swift2.3?  I will got error of "boolean condition requires where to seperate it from"

Comment: @JerryZhou, this question is explicitly tagged with "Swift3" (originally "Xcode8-beta3", and I think mixing too many things in a single thread would not be good for future readers. You'd better start a new thread with showing your code.

Comment: @OOPer thanks, I found  upgrade to  XCode8.2.1, it have been fixed.