# Many errors in project with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to use CocoaPods to install some libraries written in Swift:
[Fusuma](https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma), [TLPhotoPicker](https://github.com/tilltue/TLPhotoPicker), [DKImagePickerController](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController)

But every time I get ~300+ errors. First, I thought, that libraries are not supporting Swift 3, but in github repositories there are no issues about it and wiki said that all should be fine. Also 2 many of them are not working, so definitely, the problem is on my side.
What can be wrong? In my build settings I am using Swift 3 complier and all is up to date.

[image]

[image]

**Updates**

I tried to clean and rebuild project, didn't help.

I am using xcworkspace.

In comments there is a suggestion to update Swift 3 -> Swift 3.2, but I don't understand how to do it...? I got only 2 options: Swift 3 and Unspecified.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to clean/build and see whether the problem persists?

Comment: try setting the swift language to swift 3.2

Comment: Are you still using the `.xcodeproj` file or the new `.xcworkspace` file? after the podfile was used to install the pods, then created a new workspace. If the docs you're using show that step, or maybe they aren't

Answer (score 0):

Two of them are not working because you are using double quotation marks instead of single quotation marks:

```
pod 'TLPhotoPicker'
```

Have a look at this link to see if this solves your other problem:
[xcode 8 beta 3: Expected ',' joining parts of a multi-clause condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446598/xcode-8-beta-3-expected-joining-parts-of-a-multi-clause-condition)

I hope it helps. JL